# How to make border-top always fill the whole page

Tags: html, css

I want to make border top always full length. Everything is looking okay when my screen is equal or more than `990px`, but if I made it lower(**show the vertical scroll**) `border-top` is put only on the visible part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body style="background:aliceblue; border-top: solid 10px green;">
    <form>
       <div style="width:900px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTT
       ESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST</div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here is JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rbph1ndd/)

**How I can make the border for the whole page when the browser width is less than 990px.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make another main container and use `inline-block` and the `border` there:

```html
<body style="background:aliceblue">
    <div style="border-top: solid 10px green;display:inline-block;min-width:100%;">
    <form>
       <div style="width:900px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTT
       ESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES TTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST</div>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

Aside I reccomend you the use of `classnames` will be much easier to handle styles:

```css
.blue {
  background: aliceblue;
}
.main {
  border-top: solid 10px green;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.main form > div {
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<body class="blue">
  <div class="main">
    <form>
      <div>TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTT ESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES TTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I miss min-width ! Thanks for the fast answer. I will accept it just 3 min more.

Comment: @mybirthname glad to help U :)